# Slow Flight for CFI/Commercial Pilot - Should the gear be up or down?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

I was practicing teaching how do demonstrate slow flight in a Cessna 172RG as an instructor, and I have always just assumed that you would extend the gear for the maneuver, but when I looked at the Practical Test Standards (PTS), it doesn't specify up or down, just `selected landing gear...configurations`.

Does this mean that one should be able to demonstrate slow flight both ways, with the gear extended and with the gear retracted?

> XI. Slow Flight, Stalls, and Spins
>   ...
>
> Task A: Maneuvering During Slow Flight (ASEL and ASES)
>   ...
>
> c. Performance of the maneuver with selected landing gear and flap
>   configurations in straight-and-level flight and level turns.

Reference: [FAA-S-8081-6D](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/FAA-S-8081-6D.pdf)

Comment: *"Does this mean that one should be able to demonstrate slow flight both ways"* Hum... depends on how often you expect your trainees to land without gear extended, don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slow flight in training and testing has been the subject of much discussion and reevaluation in recent years.  The philosophy of how to train and demonstrate slow flight has changed a bit from years ago.

In specific answer to your question regarding whether or not the landing gear should be extended or not, here is an excerpt from FAA H-8083-3B [2016], page 4-4: [Airplane Flying Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/airplane_handbook/media/airplane_flying_handbook.pdf)

**(emphasis mine)**

> Slow flight is typically ***performed and evaluated in the
>   landing configuration. Therefore, both the landing gear
>   and the flaps should be extended to the landing position.***
>   It is recommended the prescribed before-landing checks
>   be completed to configure the airplane. The extension of
>   gear and flaps typically occurs once cruise power has been
>   reduced and at appropriate airspeeds to ensure limitations
>   for extending those devices are not exceeded. ***Practicing this
>   maneuver in other configurations, such as a clean or takeoff
>   configuration, is also good training and may be evaluated
>   on the practical test.***

Here is the current flight test guidance for a Commercial Pilot applicant: "Airman Certification Standards" (ACS).  Under Area of Operation VII., "Slow Flight and Stalls," Skills: CA.VII.A.S4: - [Commercial Pilot - Airplane, Airman Certification Standards - June 2017](http://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/acs/media/commercial_airplane_acs.pdf)

**(emphasis mine)**

> Accomplish coordinated straight and level flight, turns, climbs, and descents with ***landing gear*** ***and flap configurations*** ***specified by the evaluator*** without a stall warning (e.g., aircraft 
>   buffet, stall horn, etc.).

Also, here is an FAA SAFO (Safety Alert for Operations) entitled "Maneuvering During Slow Flight in an Airplane" (8/30/2016): [SAFO 16010](http://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/media/2016/SAFO16010.pdf)

Comment: This is great! Thanks! Of course the AFH has the answer! I will practice with the gear both ways. Thanks for the link to the SAFO as well.